# Error on fold when reducing in Spark / Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, fold

Given that I have a dataframe with some columns:

Why does this not work?

```
val output3b = input.withColumn("sum", columnsToConcat.foldLeft(0)((x,y)=>(x+y)))

notebook:16: error: overloaded method value + with alternatives:
 (x: Int)Int <and>
 (x: Char)Int <and>
 (x: Short)Int <and>
 (x: Byte)Int
cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.Column)
val output3b = input.withColumn("sum", columnsToConcat.foldLeft(0)((x,y)=>(x+y))) // does work
                                                                           ^
notebook:16: error: type mismatch;
found   : Int
required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
val output3b = input.withColumn("sum", columnsToConcat.foldLeft(0)((x,y)=>(x+y)))
```

But this does?

```
val output3a = input.withColumn("concat", columnsToConcat.foldLeft(lit(0))((x,y)=>(x+y)))
```

Using the famous lit function seems to smooth a few things, but I am not sure why.

```
+---+----+----+----+----+----+------+
| ID|var1|var2|var3|var4|var5|concat|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+------+
|  a|   5|   7|   9|  12|  13|  46.0|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prerequisites:

- Based on the compiler message and the API usage we can deduce that `columnsToConcat` is a `Seq[o.a.s.sql.Column]` or equivalent.
- By convention `foldLeft` methods require function that maps to the accumulator (initial value). Here's [`Seq.foldLeft` signature](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html#foldLeft[B](z:B)(op:(B,A)=%3EB):B)

  ```
   def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) ⇒ B): B
  ```
- `+`  in Scala is a method, specifically a syntactic sugar for `.+` call.

It means that in case of:

```
columnsToConcat.foldLeft(0)((x,y)=>(x+y))
```

is

```
columnsToConcat.foldLeft(0)((x: Int, y: Column) => x + y)
```

and you're asking for `+` method of `Int` (inferred type of the accumulator - `0`), and since `Int` - and there is no `+` `(org.apache.spark.sql.Column) => Int` method for [`Int`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Int.html) (the error already lists available methods, and it is hardly unexpected that such method doesn't exist), nor there exist, in the current scope, an implicit conversion from `Int` to any type that provides such method.

In the second case you're asking

```
columnsToConcat.foldLeft(lit(0))((x,y)=>(x+y))
```

is

```
columnsToConcat.foldLeft(lit(0))((x: Column, y: Column) => x + y)
```

and `+`  refers to `Column.+` (as [type of `lit(0)` is `Column`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@lit(literal:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) and such method, [which accepts`Any`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@+(other:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) and returns `Column`, exists. Since `Column <: Any` type constraints are satisfied